Issues installing Ubuntu VirtualBox VM on an external drive
I'm attempting to install an Ubuntu VirtualBox guest OS on my external drive, but I'm running into some errors. I've attached screenshots of the errors I'm receiving.



Looks like you are installing a VM Guest. Typical reasons for failure are corrupt .iso image, too small virtual disk allocated, too little RAM or Video RAM allocated. Try re-downloading the .iso image. It's big, so be sure to get the whole thing. Then double-check that your resource allocations meet the minimum requirements.
